# How to compare two Face object which gets from Google MLKit for Android

Tags: android, machine-learning, google-mlkit

I used Google Android MLKit **FaceDetectionActivity.java** for detecting to facing on image. I'll try to find how similar the faces are by comparing the two photos. How can i do it ?

```
Task<List<Face>> face1 = faceDetect(uri);
Task<List<Face>> face2 = faceDetect(uri2);
```

How can i compare face1 and face2 ?

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported by the ML Kit face detection SDK.

Comment: Which API support Face Comparision ? If you know, could you share please ?

Comment: I believe is one of the option available

https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/on-device-face-detection-on-android-using-googles-ml-kit-41f4d51bea8